# Error when using LinkedIn's datafu package

Tags: tuples, apache-pig, bigdata, bag, apache-datafu

I'm working on a project that uses the TransposeTupleToBag UDF of LinkedIn's datafu UDF compilation. Found here: https://github.com/linkedin/datafu/tree/master/src/java/datafu/pig/util. I execute the following commands in grunt shell:

```
REGISTER jar-file;

DEFINE Transpose datafu.pig.util.TransposeTupleToBag();

a = load data 'file' using PigStorage(',') as (schema);

b = foreach a generate select_columns_from_schema;

c = foreach b generate col1, col2, datafu.pig.util.Transpose(col3, col4...coln);
```

When I execute the last line, I get this error:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Instance name is null.  
This should not happen unless UDFContextSignature was not set.
```

What am I doing wrong? How to avoid it? I have not changed any of their code as well. And I'm only using TransposeTupleToBag, FieldNotFound and AliasableEvalFunc as they were the classes required to run Transpose successfully. I even tried the same with all classes loaded and it still gave me the same error. What's going on? Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TransposeTupleToBag requires a feature in Pig 0.11 where setUDFContextSignature is called.  This is used to distinguish each invocation of the UDF.  This method doesn't exist in Pig 0.10.

Comment: While I realized the same thing, your answer is far more clear than mine, in terms of addressing the specific issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, LinkedIn's datafu is tested on pig 0.11.1 and nothing else. I was running pig 0.10 and so it wouldn't work as there was some property that probably is not being set in pig 0.10, but perhaps was fixed in pig 0.11.1.